# Question marked as duplicate, but No link to duplicate question

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

Just noticed this question on Stackoverflow: [Difference between “0” and “new int()” in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171537/difference-between-0-and-new-int-in-c-sharp/) . It is marked as duplicate and closed, but I can't see any link to the original question. Is there something wrong ?

Here is a screen shot as well:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306799/why-does-c-enforce-such-behavior-in-crosses-initialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug - it was written out by a suggested edit - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13171537/revisions

Comment: ohh, never thought you could edit that out , thanks for the answer

Comment: Nng. At least one of the suggestion-approvers is on my personal blacklist... I would argue that it's very difficult to have 1000 approved and 0 rejected suggestions unless you skip all the ones you should reject. Which, of course, is feasible. Not to mention having stopped reviewing (with a few exceptions from last week) when they got the gold badge.

Comment: It should perhaps be noted that although the removal of the notice appears [in the revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13171537/5), [viewing the suggestion itself](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/919504?&_suid=1361987245149022662874939851463) does _not_ display that change. The suggestion was made to the post _before_ Community added the dupe link, and its acceptance seems to have clobbered the notice. This still wasn't a great edit, but it wasn't malicious, and the reviewers wouldn't have known about the removal. @J.Steen

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, I saw that the suggestion didn't include the intentional removal of the banner, but I still would have rejected as too minor.

Answer (score 5):

That post was edited and the duplicate notice was removed by the editor.

The other changes were not significant, so I rolled back.

Comment: Thanks for rolling it back