# Question closed as duplicate with <empty link> and also shown as "Possible duplicate"

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

When **Community** marks a question as "Possible Duplicate" and at the same time **the Question is closed** as exact duplicate, the link is missing from the 1st notice.

[image]

Examples:

- [Where are my starred Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54276/where-are-my-starred-questions)
- [Open Source Advertising - Sidebar - 1H 2010](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2010)

Can we fix this?

### References

- [Question marked as duplicate, but No link to duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169330/question-marked-as-duplicate-but-no-link-to-duplicate-question)

Comment: These are older duplicates. Basically, before February 2013, duplicate links used to be edited into the question by the Community user rather than being shown as an automatic notice. When the notices were revamped in November last year, they had to implement a hacky bypass for these older-style closures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Post Notices are live network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide) - already reported in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339706/398063), tagged as status-by-design/won't fix.

Comment: I have had success flagging these questions and requesting the moderator re-dupe using the new system. I do that every time I come across one.